# Rails Sidekiq - not connecting to Redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

Iam trying to test sidekiq and set it up as explained in the ["getting started" tutorial](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Getting-Started)

Unfortunately i get the following error message when trying to start sidekiq via bundle exec sidekiq

```
    2018-12-12T13:19:17.721Z 25023 TID-9r9if INFO: Running in ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-linux]
2018-12-12T13:19:17.721Z 25023 TID-9r9if INFO: See LICENSE and the LGPL-3.0 for licensing details.
2018-12-12T13:19:17.721Z 25023 TID-9r9if INFO: Upgrade to Sidekiq Pro for more features and support: http://sidekiq.org
2018-12-12T13:19:17.721Z 25023 TID-9r9if INFO: Booting Sidekiq 5.2.3 with redis options {:id=>"Sidekiq-server-PID-25023", :url=>nil}
**Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)**
```

I did not setup redis, since i was expecting that sidekiq brings everything it needs. Furthermore the tutorials dont talk about this...

Any idea ?

Comment: _I was expecting that sidekiq brings everything it needs._ - you're wrong, it is not magic, it's programming, there is [requirements](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq#requirements) you should read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup redis, running on your local pc. (and production environments)

https://redis.io/topics/quickstart

*For MacOS (Brew)*

```
$ brew install redis
```

And available both as brew service or via `$ redis-server` startup.

*For Ubuntu/Debian*

```
$ sudo apt install redis-server
```